# Java: Get the class of a variable

Tags: java, variables, types

For debugging purposes, I would like to display the type of a specific variable in Java, e.g.:

```
String s = "adasdas";
System.out.println( SOME_MAGIC_HERE(s) );
```

And get:

```
String
```

Comment: +1 for SOME_MAGIC_HERE(s) :D IT WAS AUTOMAGIC! Always nice to get a good laugh!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Object.getClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method.

**Examples:**

```
System.out.println(s.getClass());                  // Prints "java.lang.String"

System.out.println(s.getClass().getSimpleName());  // Prints "String"
```

Comment: Class of an object: `s.getClass()` Class of a class: `String.class` Name of a class: `clazz.getName()`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will show the canonical name of the class and the Simple name of the class.

```
package com.personal.sof;

public class GetClassOfVariable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String strVar = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(strVar.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.println(strVar.getClass().getSimpleName());

    }

}
```

o/p :

```
java.lang.String
String
```